# Angularjs - simple ng-repeat orderBy filter wont work

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-orderby

I have a simple array of objects:

```
  $scope.asd = [{"approved":true,"id":"542fb8972be5b5cc4356dd51","username":"k"},
{"approved":false,"id":"542fbea3bae6fe4449c838d5","username":"tototod"},
{"approved":false,"id":"54324929afafdb92209b2474","username":"asdasd"}
];
```

then in view i want to print the values and orderBy id or username like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in asd | orderBy:username:reverse">
{{row.username}}
</div>
```

OR

```
<div ng-repeat="row in asd | orderBy:id:reverse">
    {{row.id}}
    </div>
```

but it doesnt works, what it can be?

I have no console errors and i just followed the guide here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

any help appriciated, thanks

Comment: `reverse` is optional - you can drop it

Comment: @Grundy not if he actually wants to reverse the order!?

Comment: @Yoshi yep, but in OP not enough info :-)

Comment: @Yoshi nope indeed :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your examples `username` and `id` should be quoted! That expression has to evaluate to a string which will be used to look up the object property. Please refer to the documentation again, and you will see that `predicate` is a variable which resolves to a string value.

Solution:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in asd | orderBy:'username':true">
    {{row.username}}
</div>
```

Also, `reverse` should evaluate to a boolean expression.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2trwtvb/1/) for your data.

Comment: No problem, just be careful about what is an expression or what a variable. That way you'll avoid a lot of headaches.

Comment: yeah thank you, i didnt noticed the quotes :D you saved my day thanks